# How to check the Success Or Failed status of the External job Via oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

My database version is R11.2 and Apex 19.2.I am calling a external job(shell script) using DBMS_SCHEDULER.All are working fine.my issue is that how to get the status of the external job(shell script:0-success 1-Error) in oracle apex page and is it possible to download the external shell script log file or display log message of external shell script in same apex page?

The query SELECT * FROM dba_scheduler_job_log WHERE job_name = 'MYJOBNAME' showing "SUCCEEDED" even the external job failed.

```
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
 job_name => 'APEXDATA.myJobName',
 job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
 job_action => '/tmp/1.sh',
 enabled => FALSE,
 repeat_interval => NULL);
```

Executing below command from Apex page

```
 begin
 dbms_scheduler.run_job(job_name => 'APEXDATA.myJobName', use_current_session=> TRUE);
 end;
```

Comment: do you want the log of the shell script displayed in apex ?

Comment: The shell script is generating a log file. Same file i need to display on apex page in both success  and failed  case

Answer (score 2):

The EXECUTABLE type of DBMS_SCHEDULER needs the credential name of the user who runs the shell script. As long as the shell script is handling the error, the API of the Scheduler will exit with error. But you won't get the error itself of the script, but a generic message of DBMS_SCHEDUELER.

Let me show you with a 12.2 and type EXTERNAL_SCRIPT

```
SQL> select credential_name from dba_credentials ;

CREDENTIAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORA_FTPFDM
ORA_FTPCPL

SQL> begin
  2  dbms_scheduler.create_job ( job_name => 'MY_TEST' , job_type => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT' , job_action => '/home/ftpcpl/test.sh' ,
  3  credential_name => 'ora_ftpcpl' , enabled => false );
  4* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> ! vi /home/ftpcpl/test.sh

SQL> host chmod +x /home/ftpcpl/test.sh

SQL> host cat /home/ftpcpl/test.sh
#!/bin/bash

var=1
echo $var

# control error

return=$?

if [[ $return -eq 0 ]]; then exit 0; else exit 99; fi
```

We run the script from sqlplus and it works, as well as the scheduler job

```
SQL> host /home/ftpcpl/test.sh
    1

SQL> host echo $?
0

SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.run_job ( 'MY_TEST' ) ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now let's change the script again to force an error.

```
SQL>  host cat /home/ftpcpl/test.sh
#!/bin/bash

var=1
echo $var

# control error

return=99

if [[ $return -eq 0 ]]; then exit 0; else exit 99; fi

SQL> host vi /home/ftpcpl/test.sh

SQL> host /home/ftpcpl/test.sh
1

SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.run_job ( 'MY_TEST' ) ;
BEGIN dbms_scheduler.run_job ( 'MY_TEST' ) ; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: Cannot assign
requested address
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 238
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 568
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Conclusion: DBMS_SCHEDULER using job types EXECUTABLE or EXTERNAL_SCRIPT ( 12c onwards ) relays in the subsystem in charge to run the job. In this case the STDERR or standard error from Linux is giving back the error to the Scheduler API.

I was myself in a situation where APEX is triggering jobs run by the DBMS_SCHEDULER. In order to show the real error, I designed a process to upload the logfile to a table and parsing the column in order to deliver the log message to the APEX front end. To make it user-friendly,so to speak.

Comment: @Munu, if the job failed , as in my example, it shows FAILED in the field STATE of DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS . Your sh script is handling the errors ?